# SQL statement error in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

This is the SQL statement which I taken from debug mode in VB.Net.

```
SELECT  dt_Date as 'Date', 
        s_Time as 'Time', 
        s_For as 'For', 
        s_Categ as 'Category', 
        s_Count as 'Count', 
        s_Remarks as 'Remarks' 
FROM Entry 
WHERE (s_ENo = '22' and dt_date BETWEEN '06-05-16' And '27-05-16')
```

I am not sure what's wrong with the above statement since everything seems to be fine to my eyes.

**Description of the Error Message**

> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string.

Any suggestions how to solve this riddle?

Comment: Use ISO-8601 dates: `20160506` and `20160527`. `YYYYMMDD` format is culture/language independent.

Comment: @lad2025, Not sure how to use it and how it will help in my queries since most of the queries relies on date.

Comment: Just replace `'06-05-16'` with `'20160506'`

Comment: DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString this is the syntax which is arriving the dates in SQL query

Comment: And there is the problem, I guess you have mistmatch `dd-mm-yyyy` vs `mm-dd-yyyy` and 27 is not valid month, plus you should always use full year. **[Demo](http://rextester.com/RTM56633)**

Comment: As Dan suggests, don't convert your `DateTime` values *into* strings in the first place, just to then force SQL Server to have to convert them back into `datetime` values, and you'll avoid these conversion issues.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server?  Why have you tagged both?  Please only select the correct tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MS-SQL server than use following instructions.

The basic solution is that you have to provide date into either mm/DD/YYYY format or in YYYY-MM-DD date format into ms-sql query.

So, before passing date to query convert your date into either mm/DD/YYYY format or in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your suggestions which helps me to fix my issue.  This change made my sql code to work perfectly. DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: Unfortunately, the previous answer where I point this out has been deleted. The SQL `set dateformat dmy select MONTH(CAST('1978-05-06' as datetime))` demonstrates that there can be circumstances where SQL Server will interpret 8 digits separated by dashes in 4,2,2 grouping where it interprets it as `YYYY-DD-MM` rather than `YYYY-MM-DD`. So this is *not* a safe format to use. Either remove the dashes (if you insist on using strings) or use *parameters* and stop playing around with strings entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Instead if string literals, use strongly-typed parameters.  In addition to avoiding data type conversion issues on the SQL Server side, parameters:

- Avoid the need to format date/time string literals in a particular way
- Improve performance by providing execution plan resue
- Prevent SQL injection (barring dynamic SQL on the server side)

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your date string to YYYYMMDD or if you know the server date format then format same as server